# Maven dependencies fail to download

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I am working in a corporate network.

I can't download artifacts through maven, but I can download them individually through my web browser.

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.9.8 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused: connect @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.3.RELEASE, C:\Users\alfonso\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom, line 605, column 25
```

For what I have googled, a lot of people solve this configuring a proxy. I don't understand why I would need that, because as I said, I can download the dependencies trough my web browser.

If configuring a proxy is the only way, any idea as to how to identify my company's proxy?? I've no idea what it is.
Is it supposed to be a "maven proxy" or just a simple proxy? I ask because IT people probably don't know much about java and maven. So if I ask them what is our maven proxy, they may not know what I'm talking about (if it is something at all he he)

Comment: You must have a proxy configured in MAVEN_OPTS or settings.xml.

Comment: I do not have this error running the clean command on Eclipse. But I do have this error if I run the clean command on IntelliJ or in the CMD command line. I'd like to use IntelliJ to work, any idea what can be happening?

Comment: Probably you have configured your corporate proxy in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the dependencies through a browser is a nightmare because standard Maven projects need hundreds of artifacts (Maven plugins etc.).

The proxy is not a "Maven proxy", but a company thing. You need to find out which proxy allows access to MavenCentral. If you don't have such proxy, you need to discuss a solution like e.g. setting up your own Nexus/Artifactory and giving it access to MavenCentral.